# Spring Batch Job Stop Using jobOperator

Tags: spring-batch, spring-batch-job-monitoring

I have Started my job using `jobLauncher.run(processJob,jobParameters);` and when i try stop job using another request `jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId());` then get exeption :

> org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobExecutionNotRunningException:
> JobExecution must be running so that it can be stopped

```
Set<JobExecution> jobExecutionsSet= jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("processJob");
        for (JobExecution jobExecution:jobExecutionsSet) {
            System.err.println("job status : "+ jobExecution.getStatus());
            if (jobExecution.getStatus()== BatchStatus.STARTED|| jobExecution.getStatus()== BatchStatus.STARTING || jobExecution.getStatus()== BatchStatus.STOPPING){
                jobOperator.stop(jobExecution.getId());
                System.out.println("###########Stopped#########");
            }
        }
```

when print job status always get  `job status : STOPPING` but batch job is running

its web app, first upload some CSV file and start some operation using spring batch and during this execution if user need stop then stop request from another controller method come and try to stop running job

Please help me for stop running job

Comment: Does this mean `jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions("processJob")` returns job executions in `STOPPING` status? Are your jobs running in in the same JVMs? Please share more details about your setup (are the job launcher and joboperator sharing the same datasource?).

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine Yes its web app, first upload some csv file and start some operation using spring batch and during this execution if user need stop then stop request from another controller method come and try to stop running job

Answer (score 0):

If you stop a job while it is running (typically in a `STARTED` state), you should not get this exception. If you have this exception, it means you have stopped your job while it is currently stopping (that is what the `STOPPING` status means).

`jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions` returns only running executions, so if in the next line right after this one you have a job in `STOPPING` status, this means the status changed right after calling `jobExplorer.findRunningJobExecutions`. You need to be aware that this is possible and your controller should handle this case.

Comment: but i show execution of some process for my file when get this exeption. means jobs is running

Answer (score 0):

When you tell spring batch to stop a job it goes into STOPPING mode. What this means is it will attempt to complete the unit of work chunk it is currently processing but then stop working. Likely what's happening is you are working on a long running task that is not finishing a unit of work (is it hung?) so it can't move from STOPPING to STOPPED.

Doing it twice rightly leads to an Exception because your job is already STOPPING by the time you did it the first time.